# How to connect meteor mongo which is running on different port?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, port, minimongo

How to connect meteor mongo which is running on different port?

I ran meteor on different port using following command

```
meteor --port=3010
```

I know that minimongo is running on 3011 port. Now i want to connect to mongoshell using 'meteor mongo' command, but it is not working..

Comment: Works perfectly for me. I just run `meteor mongo` in the folder for the application and it automatcally connects to the correct port

Comment: you need to  enter `meteor mongo` from a different terminal window while running your meteor app. make sure you `cd` to same directory.